# @RequestMapping that is only mapped for @Profile

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

Is it possible to create a method level `@RequestMapping` that is only mapped if a certain profile is active?

I know it is possible to have the controller created only if a specific profile is active, but I am referring specifically to method `@RequestMapping` s at the method level

Answer (score 4):

No. Profiles affect only bean creation, not method. So you either create the whole controller or no.

Your options:

1) Create a controller with the methods that have to be available only for the given profile.

2) If you don't want to create a dedicated controller for the given method that has to be created only for a given profile you can programmatically check the active profiles and return 404 or whatever you want.

```
@Autowired
Environment environment;

public boolean isMyProfileActive() {
    for (final String profileName : environment.getActiveProfiles()) {
        if("mySpecificProfile".equals(profileName)) return true;
    }   
    return false;
}

@RequestMapping(...)
public ResponseEntity<?> myMethod(){
     if(isMyProfileActive()) return new ResponseEntity(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
     //the rest of the code for the method
}
```

Comment: This makes me wonder if the class that parses @ RequestMapping can be overridden to implement this logic. Ex if I create another annotation like @ RequestMappingProfile("profile.name"). Then I can override the class that parses the @ RequestMapping annotations to also parse the @RequestMappingProfile annotation as well and only map the URI if the profile "profile.name" is enabled. I'm not sure what class parses the @ RequestMapping annotations though.

Answer (score 2):

No.

Taken from spring docs:

> The @Profile annotation may be used in any of the following ways:
>
> - as a type-level annotation on any class directly or indirectly
>   annotated with @Component, including @Configuration classes
> - as a meta-annotation, for the purpose of composing custom stereotype
>   annotations
> - as a method-level annotation on any @Bean method
>
> If a
> @Configuration class is marked with @Profile, all of the @Bean methods
> and @Import annotations associated with that class will be bypassed
> unless one or more of the specified profiles are active. This is very
> similar to the behavior in Spring XML: if the profile attribute of the
> beans element is supplied e.g., , the beans
> element will not be parsed unless profiles 'p1' and/or 'p2' have been
> activated. Likewise, if a @Component or @Configuration class is marked
> with @Profile({"p1", "p2"}), that class will not be
> registered/processed unless profiles 'p1' and/or 'p2' have been
> activated.

Answer (score 0):

But you can have multiple controllers, so put the profile specific methods into a new one and mark it with your `@Profile("special_profile")`